# the nth root of the integral of the nth power of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Given f is a continuous real-valued function on the interval [a,b] and $f(x) \geq 0$ for all x in the interval, show that: 
$$\lim_{n \mapsto \infty }(\int_{b}^{a}(f(x))^ndx )^{\frac{1}{n}}=max\left \{f(x):x\in [a,b]  \right\}.$$
Can anybody check what I did?
I attempt to squeeze the integral.

For the upper bound, since $max[f(x)] \geq f(x)$ for all x in  the interval, we have $$(\int_{b}^{a}(f(x))^ndx )^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq [(b-a).max[f(x)]^n]^{\frac{1}{n}}=(b-a)^{\frac{1}{n}}.max[f(x)]$$
For the lower bound, using the continuity of $f(x)$ at $x_0$ where $f(x_0)=max[f(x)]$ we can find a subinterval $[c,d] \in [a,b]$ in which $max[f(x)] -f(x) \leq \epsilon $ for an abitrary $\epsilon $. Then:
$$(\int_{b}^{a}(f(x))^ndx )^{\frac{1}{n}}= \left ( \int_{a}^{c}(f(x))^ndx +\int_{c}^{d}(f(x))^ndx +\int_{d}^{b}(f(x))^ndx  \right )^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$\geq (\int_{d}^{c}(f(x))^ndx)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$\geq (d-c)^{\frac{1}{n}}.[max[f(x)]-\epsilon]  $$
Taking the limit of both bounds and noting that we can get $\epsilon$ as close to 0 as we want, we obtain the desired result.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Should the limit be as n goes to infinity?

Comment: yes my bad. I had it fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$M=max\left \{f(x):x\in [a,b]  \right\}.$$
I think the following part is obviously fine to prove the upper bound (as you suggested).

$$(\int_{a}^{b}(f(x))^ndx )^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq [(b-a).max[f(x)]^n]^{\frac{1}{n}}=(b-a)^{\frac{1}{n}}.M$$ which in turn implies $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\int_{a}^{b}(f(x))^ndx )^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq M$$

As for the lower bound, you may go like this: Since f is continuous, for a given $\epsilon > 0$ there is an interval $[c,d] \in [a,b]$ in which $f(x) \geq M-\epsilon$, and hence 
$$(\int_{a}^{b}(f(x))^ndx )^{\frac{1}{n}} \geq (\int_{c}^{d}(f(x))^ndx )^{\frac{1}{n}} \geq (M-\epsilon)(\int_{c}^{d}dx )^{\frac{1}{n}} = (M-\epsilon) (d-c)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Now, we conclude $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\int_{a}^{b}(f(x))^ndx )^{\frac{1}{n}} \geq (M-\epsilon)$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, the conclusion follows.